# echo %PATH is not working on macOS

Tags: shell, npm, macos-sierra

When I type echo %PATH it returns %PATH why?
The reason I am asking is because npm installations works fine but my packages are not in the path.

I have installed Ionic with npm i -g ionic and I can se the lib in /Users/mha/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules but when I write ionic -v I get a unknown command back.

Comment: Do you mean `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *nix systems, environment variables are preceded by a `$`, not a `%`.

You should try a `echo $PATH`

Comment: Thanks, I must have been very tired last night.